# php - How to filter out values and print them in another array

Tags: php, printing, filtering

How can I filter out my values out of an array and print them later?
The filtering can be done with:

```
$array = explode("<br>", $list);
foreach( $array as $key => $value){
    if (
        strpos(strtolower($value),'item to be filtered') !== FALSE ||
        strpos(strtolower($value),'another item to be filtered') !== FALSE
    ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
};
$newcontent = "<pre>".implode("\n",$array)."</pre>";
```

but how can I print the filtered data else where?

Comment: Store filtered values in another array.

Comment: aside comment : you can probably use [`stripos()`](https://www.php.net/stripos) instead of `strpos(strtolower())`.

Comment: @u_mulder please provide example

Comment: `$anotherArray[] = 'value';`

Comment: this just prints the word value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @u_mulder said, you should store the result in another array.

You can also use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter), and avoid the `unset()` call.

```
$list = "item to BE filtered<br>test<br>test<br>text another item to BE filtered";

$array = explode("<br>", $list);
$other = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return stripos($value,'item to be filtered') === FALSE &&
        stripos($value,'another item to be filtered') === FALSE;
});

$newcontent = "<pre>".implode("\n", $other)."</pre>";
```

Comment: this does not filter my array

Comment: @MarkdeGraaff Sorry, I've printed "$array" instead of "$other".
See https://3v4l.org/2XIZp